# Multi-column sort on bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have an MVC app with a bootstrap table - using the following library: [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)

This populates the data through a simple call

```
<table data-toggle="table"
   data-url="/myControllerActionReturningJsonData">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="column1">Column1</th>
    <th data-field="column2">Column2</th>
    <th data-field="column3">Column3</th>
    <th data-field="column4">Column4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

This is populating the table as expected and I've added the data-sortable=true tag to the columns to allow me to sort them. What I really want to do is to be able to sort the data by column 1 **and then** by column 2. So it sorts by column 1 values first and then orders the second column values.

Has anyone got any idea on how best to implement this? Ideally I'd like to keep the sorting on the client rather than sorting server-side.

Comment: Hi, it does not support this feature in current version.

Comment: Are you looking for [multiple-sort](https://bootstrap-table.com/versions/1.15.5/docs/extensions/multiple-sort/)?